# Insertion of characters into number column

Tags: oracle

I have a table with several number columns that are inserted through a Asp.Net application using bind variables.
Due to upgrade of Oracle client to 19c and server change, the code instead of giving an error on insert of invalid data, inserts trash and the application crashes aftewards.
Any help is appreciated in finding the root cause.

```
SELECT trial1,
       DUMP (trial1, 17),
       DUMP (trial1, 1016),
       trial3,
       DUMP (trial3,17),
       DUMP (trial3, 1016)
```

Result in SQL Navigator
[results of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icb6j.jpg)

Oracle 12c
Oracle client 19

My DBA found this on Oracle Support and that lead to us find the error in the application side:

> NaN is a specific IEEE754 value. However Oracle NUMBER is not IEEE754
> compliant. Therefore if you force the data representing NaN into a
> NUMBER column results are unpredicatable. SOLUTION If you can put a
> value in a C float, double, int etc you can load this into the
> database as no checks are undertaken - just as with the Oracle NUMBER
> datatype it's up to the application to ensure the data is valid. If
> you use the proper IEEE754 compliant type, eg BINARY_FLOAT, then NaN
> is recognised and handled correctly.

Comment: Why are you using `DUMP(17, trial1)` rather than `DUMP(trial1, 17)`?

Comment: Because I wanted to know what is really in the column. The problem started with a round(trial1,3) giving invalid number, which for me was not possible due to trial1 being a number column.

Comment: Look at the [syntax diagram for the `DUMP` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm#SQLRF00635). You want `DUMP(expr, return_fmt)` which would be `DUMP(trial1, 17)`. You have the arguments the wrong way round as you are putting the `return_fmt` into the `expr` argument and vice-versa.

Comment: @MT0 thanks, my bad. updated question with correct values

Answer (score 1):

You have bad data as you have tried to store an double precision NAN value in a `NUMBER` column rather than a `BINARY_DOUBLE` column.

---

We can duplicate the bad data with the function (never use this in a production environment):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION createNumber(
  hex VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  n NUMBER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.CONVERT_RAW_VALUE( HEXTORAW( hex ), n );
  RETURN n;
END;
/
```

Then, we can duplicate your bad values using the hexadecimal values from your `DUMP` output:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (trial1 NUMBER, trial3 NUMBER);
INSERT INTO table_name (trial1, trial3) VALUES (
  createNumber('FF65'),
  createNumber('FFF8000000000000')
);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT trial1,
       DUMP(trial1, 16) AS t1_hexdump,
       trial3,
       DUMP(trial3, 16) AS t3_hexdump
FROM   table_name;
```

Replicates your output:

> | TRIAL1 | T1_HEXDUMP | TRIAL3 | T3_HEXDUMP |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | ~ | Typ=2 Len=2: ff,65 | *null* | Typ=2 Len=8: ff,f8,0,0,0,0,0,0 |

---

> Any help is appreciated in finding the root cause.

You need to go back through your application and work out where the bad data came from and see if you can determine what the original data was and debug the steps it went through in the application to work out if it was:

1. Always bad data, and then you need to put in some validation into your application to make sure the bad data does not get propagated; or
2. Was good data but there is a bug in your code that changed it and then you need to fix the bug.

As for the existing bad data, you either need to correct it (if you know what it should be) or delete it.

We cannot help with any of that as we do not have visibility of your application nor do we know what the correct data should have been.

---

If you want to store that data as a floating point then you need to change from using a `NUMBER` to using a `BINARY_DOUBLE` data type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value BINARY_DOUBLE);
INSERT INTO table_name(value) VALUES (BINARY_DOUBLE_INFINITY);
INSERT INTO table_name(value) VALUES (BINARY_DOUBLE_NAN);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT value,
       DUMP(value, 16)
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | DUMP(VALUE,16) |
> | --- | --- |
> | Inf | Typ=101 Len=8: ff,f0,0,0,0,0,0,0 |
> | Nan | Typ=101 Len=8: ff,f8,0,0,0,0,0,0 |

Then `BINARY_DOUBLE_NAN` exactly matches the binary value in your column and you have tried to insert a Not-A-Number value into a `NUMBER` column (that does not support it) in the format expected for a `BINARY_DOUBLE` column (that would support it).

Comment: I know that is bad data, I wanted to understand how it was possible to do it and I think I found the problem. There was a calculation in c# or JS that was infinity and that the value that appears in the table, the problem is that Oracle is not full compliant with some floating point standard. Thanks for the help

Comment: @EduardoReis The Oracle `NUMBER` data type is not a floating point number; it stores the digits exactly (using 2 digits per bit). If you want a floating point number then use the `BINARY_FLOAT` or `BINARY_DOUBLE` data types [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=33167f562b87df1d3c106088acfcaf00). So its not that Oracle is not compliant, its that you're using the wrong data-type for the data if you want to store infinity.

Comment: @EduardoReis On further investigation, it is not Infinity, it is `BINARY_DOUBLE_NAN` you are trying to store. (But you still want to use a `BINARY_DOUBLE` column and not a `NUMBER`)

Comment: I don't want to store infinity, it was an error in the app! I just want to store a couple of decimal places, thanks for the explanation and all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a division by zero on the application side that was inserted as infinity into the database, but Oracle has an unpredictable behavior with this values.
Please see original post above for all the details.